# Repeating bullets outside of container

Tags: html, css

It's a html / css issue which I am having. I have attached a screenshot, the bullets need to continue outside of the container to the browser edge, ready for the next slide. Any methods I have tried, just do not work as once the browser responds it just goes out of proportion.

Any css tricks would be fantastic.

Adam[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9rLb.jpg)

Comment: Post the code work till you have done

Comment: You can make sure overflow is not hidden on third element and that whatever container the bullets are in, that the line doesn't wrap. `white-space: nowrap;`